# Supplemental Spousal Liability NY

Tags: new-york-state, insurance, vehicle

I was always under the impression that Bodily Injury Liability  pays out to to other driver, other driver's passengers, and your own passengers.

After reading the below, "your own passengers" actually means your own passengers except your spouse. Is this interpretation correct? In order for a spouse to be paid under Bodily Injury Liability, Supplemental Spousal Liabilty must be requested and added as a rider? Or, as a passenger, she would still be covered for bodily injury as long as one carriers Bodily Injury Liability?

"Bars coverage under a liability policy for claims brought by a spouse against the other spouse unless the policy expressly provides coverage for such claims."

Would anyone be able to elaborate?

Comment: You question reads as if you are quoting something that didn't make it into the question. What are you quoting and what exactly are you asking? You don't seem confused about what the language means.

Comment: @ohwilleke The quote was from legal website. My interpretation is only my interpretation. Question is for someone who knows more specifics regarding NYS law, or has actually had involvement in this and whether my interpretation is spot on.

Comment: I'm familiar with NYS law (I'm admitted to the practice of law there), but I still don't know what you are asking when you say "Would anyone be able to elaborate?"

Comment: @ohwilleke - Saw that. Edited question. Hoping clearer?

Comment: This is much clearer. Before I wasn't clear if you were asking if this was a correct statement of the law, or how someone felt about that as a matter of history and policy.

Comment: @ohwilleke will you be able to answer?  I was looking into this a bit and was confused by what I found.  I hope you will be able to post something.